# How to render a parent component upon clicking a child component in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have three components each one being a parent of the other. I want to render the entire parent component upon clicking a child component. What is the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React: How to render a parent component from child component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36724758/react-how-to-render-a-parent-component-from-child-component)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can update state of parent component from child component. Parent will then re-render automatically.

Or

You can pass `forceUpdate` method of parent component as a prop to child component. Whenever child component will call that method (e.g. on onClick handler), parent will re render.

**Reference:**

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate